# Knight's Travails in ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, chess

The task was to build a `knight_moves` method which when called would display the simplest path from one given square to the other given square.

#### My Solution:

```
class Square
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :children, :parent
  def initialize(x,y, parent=nil)
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @children = []
    @parent = parent
  end
end

def create_children(board)
  potentials = []
  potentials.push(
    [board.x + 2, board.y + 1],
    [board.x + 2, board.y - 1],
    [board.x + 1, board.y + 2],
    [board.x + 1, board.y - 2],
    [board.x - 2, board.y + 1],
    [board.x - 2, board.y - 1], 
    [board.x - 1, board.y + 2], 
    [board.x - 1, board.y - 2]
    )

  valid_children = potentials.select do |space|
    space[0].between?(0,8) &&
    space[1].between?(0,8)
  end

  valid_children = valid_children.map do |space|
    Square.new(space[0], space[1], board)
  end
  @children = valid_children
end

def knight_moves(first_square,final_square)
  first_children = Square.new(first_square[0],first_square[1])
  create_children(first_children)
  bfs(final_square, @children)
end

def bfs(search_value,children)
  queue = children

  loop do 
    current = queue.shift
    if [current.x,current.y] == search_value 
      display_path(current)
      break
    else
      create_children(current).each {|child| queue << child}
    end
  end
end

def display_path(current)
  parent = current.parent
  array = []
  while !parent.nil?
    array << [parent.x,parent.y]
    parent = parent.parent
  end
  array.reverse!
  array << [current.x,current.y]
  puts "Your path is:"
  array.each {|i| p i}
end
```

#### Method Call

```
knight_moves([2,5],[4,7])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bug

This:

```
knight_moves([2,5],[2,5])
```

prints:

```
Your path is:
[2, 5]
[4, 6]
[2, 5]
```

Not the shortest path. In `knight_moves`, simply call `bfs` with `[first_child]` as the `children` argument. There's no need to call `create_children` in `knight_moves`; `bfs` can compute the first level of the search tree the same way it computes all other levels.

### Global variable

In `create_children`, you're setting `@children` which acts like a global variable as this method isn't inside a class. Simply return `valid_children` without setting any variables.

(You're not setting `Square#children` because the method isn't inside `Square`. You actually never use `Square#children`. Remove this field from `Square`).

### Naming

Rename:

- `Square` -> `Node` (The class represents a node in the search tree. A true `Square` class would only have `x` and `y` fields).
- `create_children` -> `child_nodes`
- `first_children` -> `root`
- `board` argument -> `node` (or `parent`)
- `display_path` -> `print_path`

### Missing `Square` class

The code sometimes uses an `[x, y]` array for squares, and sometimes the `x` and `y` fields of `Node`. This makes the code full of wrapping of unwrapping:

```
# lines that unwrap an [x, y] array:
Node.new(space[0], space[1], board)
first_child = Node.new(first_square[0],first_square[1])

# lines that create an [x, y] array:
if [current.x,current.y] == search_value 
array << [current.x,current.y]
```

You can eliminate this by creating a `Square` class and use it for representing squares everywhere in the code (including in `Node`):

```
class Square
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def ==(other)
    [self.x, self. y] == [other.x, other.y]
  end

  def to_s
    [self.x, self.y].to_s
  end
end
```

I already implemented equality (for the comparison in `bfs`) and `to_s` (for printing in `print_path`). Then change `Node` to use a `Square`: (also, use `attr_reader`)

```
class Node
  attr_reader :square, :parent
  def initialize(square, parent=nil)
    @square = square
    @parent = parent
  end
end
```

Now replace any `[x, y]` array in the code with a `Square`:

```
# in child_nodes:
square = node.square
...
Square.new(square.x + 2, square.y + 1),
...
space.x.between(0, 8) &&
...
Node.new(space, node)

# in knight_moves:
Node.new(first_square)

# in bfs:
if current.square == search_value

# in print_path:
array << parent.square
array << current.square
puts i # instead of "p i", so to_s is used

# calling knight_moves:
knight_moves(Square.new(2, 5), Square.new(4, 7))
```

### Missing `Square` methods

Most of `child_nodes` deals with squares, so most of its functionality should be inside `Square` methods. The only thing it does that doesn't involve only squares is creating nodes, so it should do just that:

```
def child_nodes(node)
  node.square.knight_moves.map do |square|
    Node.new(square, node)
  end
end
```

`Square#knight_moves` is a new method that returns an array of the squares that can be reached from the current one. It should look something like this:

```
def knight_moves
  [
    Square.new(self.x + 2, self.y + 1),
    ...
  ].select { |square| square.valid? }
end
```

This requires adding a `Square#valid?` to check if a square's coordinates are legal.

### Revisiting `knight_moves`

`knights_moves` does too little now, it only creates a root node and put it in a one-element array. I would remove it and move its functionality to `bfs` (Make `bfs` accept `first_square` and `final_square` as arguments, and call it directly).

### Seperating logic and printing

Don't print the path in `bfs`, just return it (the array of squares) and let the main code print it. You can simplify the code for getting the path:

```
def path_from_root(current)
  array = []
  loop do
    array << current.square
    current = current.parent
    break if current.nil?
  end
  array.reverse
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Spike. I am still pouring through this but really appreciate you taking the time to offer feedback.